# Bing Video Search API 401: Access denied due to missing subscription key

Tags: javascript, api, axios, bing

I'm making a get request using axios to the Bing Video Search API. I believe I'm using the correct code to make the request, but I keep getting a 401: access denied due to missing subscription key. I included the required subscription key in the header, but I'm still getting this error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
export const fetchBingVideos = term => async dispatch => {
const res = await axios.get(
    "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/videos/search",
    {
        headers: {
            "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "*************"
        }
    },
    {
        params: {
            count: 10,
            mkt: "en-US",
            q: term
        }
    }
);

dispatch({ type: FETCH_OFFENSE_VIDEOS, payload: res.data.items });
};
```

Comment: Is this the API documentation ~ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-video-api-v7-reference ?

Comment: Do you happen to have any Axios interceptors configured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue is that `params` and `headers` should be part of the same object. `axios.get()` only accepts two arguments but you are providing three.

Try

```js
axios.get('https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/videos/search', {
  headers: {
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '**********'
  },
  params: {
    count: 10,
    mkt: 'en-US,
    q: term
  }
})
```

Comment: You're welcome. Bing's error messages could use some work, that's for sure